# DOMDocument encoding issue when scraping a page

Tags: php

I'm scraping a google play link for some information to retrieve the app name.

The problem is that some applications return unreadable characters.

```
        $div2 = $div->getElementsByTagName("div");
        if ($div2->length)
        {
            $gpAppName = DOMinnerHTML($div2->item(0));
            $counter++;
            if(checkIfMaxedOutAndReturn($counter)){
                buildObjAndReturn($gpIcon,$gpBg,$gpAppName,$gpBtnLink);
            }
        }
        function DOMinnerHTML($element)
        {
            $innerHTML = "";
            $children = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($children as $child)
            {
                $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
                $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true));
                $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML());
            }
            return $innerHTML;
        }
```

When scrapping the page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vascogames.TransportTruck, the code you see here will scrape the App name which is "Truck Driver – Cargo delivery" but the code returns "Truck Driver â€“ Cargo delivery"

Comment: Did you specify the encoding in the constructor? http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

Comment: @somedev, yes $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');

Comment: Present [a self-contained testcase](http://sscce.org). You've been here for 2 years and asked 80 questions, so you should know how it works. You just need to take the time and put in the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky, the underlying libxml2 library looks for HTML tags that specify the encoding, and the Google Play page doesn't provide any. Here's a quick solution which injects a meta tag into the source before parsing it:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vascogames.TransportTruck';

$source = file_get_contents($url);
$source = str_replace(
  '<head>',
  '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">',
  $source
);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($source);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($divs as $div) {
  if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'document-title') {
    echo trim($div->textContent);
    echo "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: thx, but didn't work, the new result is: Truck Driver &ndash; Cargo delivery

Comment: @Alon I've edited my answer. Try it again. `saveHTML` outputs HTML-escaped text, that was why you were seeing `&ndash;` instead of –.

Comment: it stills outputs the &ndash;

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what else code you have beside what I've given you. My snippet works just fine in a terminal.